# Which generic module are you using to read MySQL ini configuration file?

Tags: perl

There is a lot of modules on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) about reading/writing INI files, but every modules I have tested so far ([Config::General](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aGeneral), [Config::IniFiles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aIniFiles), [Config::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aSimple), [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aTiny)) failed to read my **MySQL** ***my.cnf*** file.

They all failed because of syntax like this (line with key but without value):

```
skip-external-locking
```

So, which module are you using to read MySQL ini configuration file AND other programs ini files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to patch [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aTiny) to handle non-standard MySQL stuff...

I pushed my modified module on GitHub:

https://github.com/sebthebert/Perl-Shots/blob/master/Modules/Config/Tiny.pm

Diff:

```
8c8
<   $Config::Tiny::VERSION = '2.12';
---
>   $Config::Tiny::VERSION = '2.13';
66a67,76
>       # Handle 'non-standard' MySQL properties
>       if ( /^\s*([-_a-z]+)\s*$/i ) {
>                   $self->{$ns}->{$1} = 1;
>                   next;
>           }
>       # Drop 'non-standard' MySQL '!include' & '!includedir' directives
>       if ( /^\s*!include(dir)?\s+\S+\s*$/ ) {
>           next;
>       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but there is apparently [MySQL::Config](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MySQL%3a%3aConfig)

Comment: Yes this module handles well 'skip-external-locking', but I would like a generic module, not a 'MySQL only' one.

Comment: @sethebert my.cfg syntax doesn't seem to follow accepted conventions for ini files http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_files and can't be expected to  work well with generic parsers. You might need a specific solution.

Comment: @sebthebert - you may have to extend an existing module, such as `Config::IniFiles`. But may I inquire which features of "generic" INI files the MySQL::Config module doesn't support? It seemed to me like it is fairly generic, except for the name. I'm not faimiliar enough with the spec to judge with certainty

Comment: @sebthebert - Good point. The problem is basically `load_defaults()` method, specifically ~5 lines of file handling in it ... you can probably submit a patch or create a subclass module to override `load_defaults()` - easier than rolling your own.

Comment: @DVK: I will submit a patch for Config::Tiny.